# amplify configuration not showing anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm trying to setup my mobile app with amplify, after the first time i run `amplify configuration` it prompt me that I have missing plugins.

```
The following official plugins are missing or inactive:
awscloudformation: provider | amplify-provider-awscloudformation@4.33.0
analytics: category | amplify-category-analytics@2.19.1
api: category | amplify-category-api@2.27.0
auth: category | amplify-category-auth@2.25.0
function: category | amplify-category-function@2.26.3
hosting: category | amplify-category-hosting@undefined
hosting: category | amplify-console-hosting@undefined
interactions: category | amplify-category-interactions@2.6.1
notifications: category | amplify-category-notifications@2.17.1
predictions: category | amplify-category-predictions@2.6.1
storage: category | amplify-category-storage@2.10.3
xr: category | amplify-category-xr@2.6.1
codegen: util | amplify-codegen@2.19.0
flutter: frontend | amplify-frontend-flutter@0.2.0
android: frontend | amplify-frontend-android@2.14.2
ios: frontend | amplify-frontend-ios@2.16.0
javascript: frontend | amplify-frontend-javascript@2.19.0
mock: util | amplify-util-mock@3.27.0
```

Then it asked me to select my backend provider, but there is nothing for me to choose.

[image]

I think it is cause by the missing plugin, how do I install those plugin?

Comment: Did you use npm to install it?

Comment: Sry to mention, i use  yarn global add @aws-amplify/cli

Comment: Then try following my answer :) I had the same problem

Comment: You should use npm for amplify, they aren't mentioning it in the documentation though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to re-install amplify with this command `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true`.